# How add facebook sharing meta tags?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I dont understand why facebook doesn't see my website content on meta tags. I include fb app id(but facebook sharing debugger dont see it).

Code from header.php

```
    <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
        <meta property="og:locale" content="lt_LT"/>
        <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
        <meta property="og:title" content="TEST"/>
        <meta property="og:description" content="Content TEST"/>
        <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo get_site_url();?>"/>
        <meta property="og:site_name" content="Website name TEST"/>
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff"/>
        <meta property="og:image:width" content="630" />
        <meta property="og:image:height" content="1200" />
        <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1206909562769520" />
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/lt_LT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=1206909562769520";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Function.php

```
function add_opengraph_doctype( $output ) {
    return $output . ' xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"';
}
add_filter('language_attributes', 'add_opengraph_doctype');
```

What i did wrong ? Something missing ?

Facebook sharing debugger shows :

```
fb:app_id   blank
og:url  website-URL
og:type website
og:title    website url on title.
og:description  blank
og:image    blank
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https to http redirecting issue. Solved.